# Connect to the server through SSH (tunneling)

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

[image]

Hello!!

I have a set of servers with the layout in the image attached. Lets call them Server A, B and C.
 Details for the scenario:

- Server A is where all the processing is done and user is working on A directly. Server A is really a client. :/
- Server A is connected to Server B via Ethernet. It is in its sub-net and can perform operations on Server B.
- Server B can NOT access server C (access restricted for security)
- Server C can access server B.
- Server C has Application APP installed.
- Admins can access C and can initiate any program. But user of A cannot access C.
- Client A needs data from Server C. Application APP has the data.

**Now, what I need to accomplish is to access application APP on Server C from Client A.**

Can I accomplish this using **SSH port forwarding**? Any work around for this?

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: In what way Server C can access B (what protocol) as you do not have sshd running on B

Comment: Client A is in the subnet and has sshd. Can A and C communicate through a designated port on B?

Answer (score 1):

No. Since B does not have sshd, there is no way to have C perform a reverse tunnel via it. B will have to forward a port to A.

Comment: Any wokraround?? Please consider, I can transfer files temporarily to B..

Comment: Did you read it?

Comment: I am sorry? What are you referring to? I was wondering if client A and Server C can communicate through a designated (any) port on B since both A and C has sshd and can communicate to B.

Comment: Is A server can access internet ?

Comment: nope it cannot..